# How to make form snap to certain heights when the form is resized vertically?

Tags: vb.net, variables, resize, picturebox

I have 3 PictureBoxes on a form that are tiled on top of each other. the form has a minimum vaule of (502, 416) and a maximum of (502, 1080).

because the user can select from a MenuStrip to display '1', '2' 0r '3' PictureBoxes at once '3' being the bottom and '1' being the top PictureBox. What i need is when the user drags down the form it snaps to the next PictureBoxes position, so it goes down in blocks this is what i have so far which is pretty far from working.

```
    If Me.Height <= (1079) Then
        Me.Height = (732)

    ElseIf Me.Height <= (732) Then
        Me.Height = (424)
    ElseIf 
    ...
    End If
```

I also thought i might be able to figure it out if i new how to create a variable like this

```
    If Me.Height <= (1079 to 733) Then
        Me.Height = (732)
```

I know that it isn't the correct syntax but it's kind of the idea

If you can make sense from my not so good description and point me in the right direction/code example i will be most grateful :)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i didn't quite get what you mean, i tried adding just the second example of code but the (1079 to 733) bit doesn't actually work?

Comment: Say Height is 500.  The first If statement will always be true.  You want to compare to the *smaller* value first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) Statement:

```
Select Case Me.Height

    Case 425 To 732
        Me.Height = 424

    Case 733 To 1079
        Me.Height = 732

End Select
```

---

To answer your further question. If you are going to use the Form Resize event any animation you have is going to get interesting because as you change the Form Height it will retrigger the Event. Personally if I were you I would stay with your initial idea of snapping to the next height and if you are wanting to animate the Form Height I would seriously look into WPF. But here is the SubRoutine that I said I would show you, I have used three buttons to intiatiate the resizing. Be carefull if you put this in your Form Resize Event if you don't block the event from rerunning the Subroutine it will freeze your computer.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        Me.Text = Me.Height
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeFormHeight(fromHeight As Integer, toHeight As Integer)
        If fromHeight > toHeight Then
            For newHeight As Integer = fromHeight To toHeight Step -1
                Me.Height = newHeight
            Next
        Else
            For newHeight As Integer = fromHeight To toHeight
                Me.Height = newHeight
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ChangeFormHeight(Me.Height, 424)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ChangeFormHeight(Me.Height, 733)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ChangeFormHeight(Me.Height, 1080)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much!, i had to change the numbers around a bit but it works on "form resize end" even pretty well. just one more thing... how could a make it animate between each snap so it looks smooth? i already tried doing a "do until loop" but you can't really do them with select cases and same with timers ? Thanks once again

Comment: Put your logic in a subroutine and call if from the case statement though it most likely won't work in your resize event

Comment: I really have no idea on how to do that, would you be able to send me a text file with some code if that's alright? thanks

Comment: and also when i try to do a reverse case statement like "1040 to 733" it says that the first number has to be smaller than the second, how can i get around that? :)

Comment: Why would you want to reverse your case statement ? I will try to put something together and add it to answer but it will be later today before I get back to a pc with visual studio on it

Comment: Okay thanks man :) where i am it's 10:12 pm - Australia ;) so don't rush to much, unless of course you'll be back before 12:00pm in my time? O.o Thanks!